# How to encode a query in CURL Command Line when passing a query as a sql parameter

Tags: database, api, http, curl, cypher

I am trying to query via CURL command line but I believe I need to encode it.

Example:
curl  -X GET -H "Authorization:c02c66a4531a43c5a0971d16c2823e1a" 'http://127.0.0.1:8050/api/core/query?sql=select n return n limit 10' -i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't ever see why this is a good idea, but here is a curl with an encoded `match(n) return n limit 10' -i`:

```
curl -X GET \
  http://127.0.0.1:8085/api/core/query \
  -H 'Authorization: c02c66a4531a43c5a0971d16c2823e1a' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'sql=match(n)%20return%20n%20limit%2010'\''%20-i'
```